# Enable right click menu while using OrbitControls

Tags: three.js, orbitcontrols

In Three.js, I would like to enable the context menu in order to let the user save the canvas upon right click on the image, while using `OrbitControls`.

Disabling `OrbitControls` with `controls.enabled = false;` makes the right click menu come back, but obviously disables the controls.
Only disabling the right click pan doing `controls.enablePan = false;` does not enable the right click menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't configure the behavior that you are looking for. So you have to modify `OrbitControls` by simply removing the internal `onContextMenu()` event listener.